# c# DbContext needs 20seconds

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

When i start may console program and initialized my DbContext class my program waits every time 20 seconds.

without the dbContext class all working fine.
Anyone know why?

Here someCode

```
public class CobraDataBaseContext : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<Material> Materials { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Site> Sites { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Ein Workplace hat eine Optinale Maschine ABER eine Maschine muss immer einem Workplace 
        // zugeordnet sein.
        modelBuilder.Entity<WorkPlace>().HasOptional(m => m.machine).WithRequired(wp => wp.workPlace);

        // one material has optinal specification
        modelBuilder.Entity<Material>().HasOptional(n => n.specification).WithMany();
    }
}
```

A Service class

public Site getSite(string siteName)
        {
            var site = dbContext.Sites.FirstOrDefault(s => s.name.Equals(siteName));

```
        foreach (var wp in site.workPlaces)
        {
            if (wp.numberOfWorkers != null)
            {
                double count = wp.numberOfWorkers.value.Value;
            }
        }


        return dbContext.Sites.FirstOrDefault(s => s.name.Equals(siteName));
    }
```

Comment: Show us the code you are referring to please.

Comment: Define "initialized my DbContext" ? are you just connecting? or connecting and reading a huge table? or...? have you profiled the database connection?

Comment: added code in the main text

Answer (score 2):

[The following excerpt explains what is going on](http://vbfeeds.com/post.aspx?id=7511)

> Model Caching
>
> There is some cost involved in discovering the model, processing Data Annotations and applying fluent API configuration. To avoid incurring this cost every time a derived DbContext is instantiated the model is cached during the first initialization. The cached model is then re-used each time the same derived context is constructed in the same AppDomain.

Comment: i cannot find the property to set the model caching to false

Comment: It looks to have been removed - as this process must happen for Entity Framework to function, the caching is so that it only happens once within the App Domain. If you did turn it off it would take 20 seconds for every call rather than just the first.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you: [`MSDN: Performance Considerations for Entity Framework 5`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx)

In particular, I've found that pre-compiling the views helps the most if you have a large model.